# How to upload data local inventory feed in google merchant center account using content API

Tags: java, google-content-api, google-merchant-center

I tried to use the LocalInventory class like Product class but we could not find the LocalInventory source code/jar.
Kindly help to send the data in local inventory feed using feedID or feedName via content API in java language.

I want to create to object of LocalInventory class so that we can send the following data using  its methods.

Store_code
id
stock
price

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.